# if else пару условий

Tags: php

Добрый вечер не пойму где ошибся
Нужно сделать так

Если `$ext_description` не пуст или не содержит `<p><br></p>`
То выводим `$ext_description` , а если пуст или содержит `<p><br></p>` то выводим **$attribute_groups** если он тоже пусто то ничего не делаем

```
        <?php if (!$ext_description or $ext_description != "<p><br></p>") { ?>

            <?php echo $ext_description; ?>

    <?php }elseif($attribute_groups){ ?>
        <?php echo $attribute_groups; ?>

    <?php }else{ ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаток PHP, но возможно вам подойдёт такой код:

```
<?php if ($ext_description != "" or $ext_description != "<p><br></p>") { ?>

        <?php echo $ext_description; ?>

<?php }elseif($attribute_groups){ ?>
    <?php echo $attribute_groups; ?>

<?php }else{ ?>

<?php } ?>
```

В любом случае, покажите как выглядит ошибка, так будет понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего необходимо проверить если в строке `$ext_description` `html` теги.
для этого делаем:
`$a = preg_match("/<p>/i" , $ext_description);`
Получим либо 0 либо 1.
Далее делаем необходимую проверку по вашим условиям:

```
<?php
if (strlen($ext_description)>1 || $a == 0 ) { 
        echo $ext_description;
    }elseif(strlen($attribute_groups)>1){ 
        echo $attribute_groups; 
    } else{
        echo "ничего";
    }
?>
```

Код не идеальный, но общая идея ясна.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($ext_description && $ext_description != "<p><br></p>") { 

     echo $ext_description; 

}elseif($attribute_groups && $ext_description && $ext_description == "<p><br></p>"){ 
     echo $attribute_groups; 

}else{ 

}
```

Comment: `elseif($attribute_groups && $ext_description && $ext_description == "<p><br></p>")` вот тут лишняя проверка на пустоту и присутствие тегов, так как выше обратная проверка и если она не выполнится то ветвление придёт к проверке это варианта

Answer (score -1):

Проще удалить все теги и проверить на пустоту.

```
if (!empty(strip_tags($ext_description))
    echo $ext_description;
elseif(!empty($attribute_groups))
    echo $attribute_groups;
```

Comment: Тогда мы, не узнаем, есть ли там: `<p><br></p>`. Так-как условия именно такое, если там не пусто или `<p><br></p>` то выводим.